# What is wrong with my HAR model - constantly increasing?

Tags: volatility, models

I am trying to code the HAR (and eventually the HARQ) from [Bollerslev et al 2016](http://public.econ.duke.edu/%7Eap172/BPQ_Exploiting_Errors_JoE_2016.pdf) and [Corsi 2009](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/%7Ehauser/LVs/FinEtricsQF/References/Corsi2009JFinEtrics_LMmodelRealizedVola.pdf).

$$
RV_t = \beta_0 +\beta_1 RV^d_{t-1} + \beta_2 RV^W_{t-1}+\beta_3 RV^M_{t-1}+u_t
$$

Bollerslev estimates the parameters as: $\beta_0 = 0.1123, \beta_1 = 0.2273, \beta_2 = 0.4903$, and $\beta_3= 0.1864 $

With these all being positive my $RV_t$ is just an increasing amount of $RV_{t-1}$ and approaching infinity. What have I misunderstood? I tried including the $u_t$ but this sometimes led to negative realised variance values so I assumed it was wrong.

Aside: In a lot of these realised variance papers they discuss that $RV_t = \sum^M_{i=1} r_{t,i}^2$ as the squared returns for M periods in day $t$. Then they go on to propose the HAR/HARQ etc model which is calculating $RV_t$. Are we only using the squared returns calculation for the $RV_0$ and from then on using the proposed model?

Comment: The estimates seems fine. Be aware that $RV$ does not tend to infinity empirically, unless noise is present in the time-series. So, it will (likely) not approach infinity. The estimates tells you, that the lagged daily and weekly (averaged) RV components explain todays $RV_t$ better than the monthly component (since $\beta_2 > \beta_1 > \beta_3$). Does this somewhat answer your first question? Otherwise please try to reformulate the question.

Comment: For the second question: No, we are not using the estimated $\hat{RV}_t$ from the HAR model for tomorrows estimate. The $\hat{RV}_t$ is a model estimate of todays realized variance. At the end of the day (ex-post) we can measure the "actual" realized variance $RV_t$. This is what we will be using in tomorrows HAR estimation. You can then use loss functions and comparison frameworks to measure the distance between the model estimate, $\hat{RV}_t$ and the actual ex-post $RV_t$ to observe the forecast performance of the model.

Comment: If all $RV_{t-1}$ are the same we have $RV_t =0.1123+0.904 RV_{t-1}$. If $RV$ is bigger than 1.169792 it will decrease, if it is smaller it will increase. What is the typical magnitude of RV?

Comment: @Pleb This makes 100x more sense now. I was recursively using yesterday's forecast for the $RV_{t-1}$ rather than the actual value calculated using the data. Thank you.

Comment: @BlueTurtle No problem. Glad I could help.